# How Can You Change Which Microphone Is Used During Calls?

Tags: microphone, lg-g4, audio-recording, speakerphone

My LG G4 phone's main microphone is broken but it's secondary microphone is working. That is, during ordinary calls or voice recordings, the microphone doesn't pick up any sound (completely dead) but during speakerphone calls or video recordings that microphone works fine.

Is there any way to permanently redirect the primary microphone to the secondary one, so that for ALL calls, the secondary microphone is used to pick up sound?

Comment: As this is a hardware issue, rather than software as I had thought, then try cleaning holes, gently pressing areas close to mic , or even thorough cleaning this area, and see if ot changes. But in case it didn't work then try automation as I had suggested to keep speakerphone active. Good luck

Comment: Exactly what @xavier_fakerat Use a toothbrush with a little alcohol. It will get it loose without harming the phone.

Answer (score 2):

I just found a way to do that. You can use [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) to automatically start the loudspeaker(which starts using secondary mic.) and then also add a rule to Tasker to reduce the loudspeaker volume to minimum which will very closely simulate the situation.

Comment: Problem is that the loudspeaker is at the back of the phone